# Объединить два запроса SQL

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы.
Первая таблица с компаниями `company`, поля: `company_id`, `company_name`.

Вторая таблица с актами `act`, поля: `act_id`, `receipt_date` (дата получения), `issue_date` (дата выдачи, может быть Null).

В итоге мне нужен запрос, чтобы данные были в таком виде:

`company_id`, `company_name`, `количество полученых актов за 27.02.2018`, `количество выданных актов за 27.02.2018`

`company_id`, `company_name`, `количество полученых актов за 26.02.2018`, `количество выданных актов за 26.02.2018`

и так далее...

Запросы отдельно у меня получаются, в этом нет проблем.

```
select c.id company_id, c.name company, DATE(receipt_date) receipt, count(*) count from act
join company c on c.id = act.company_id
where 

    act.is_delete = 0
group by act.company_id, receipt
```

```
select c.id company_id, c.name company, DATE(issue_date) issue, count(*) count from act
    join company c on c.id = act.company_id
    where 

        act.is_delete = 0
    group by act.company_id, issue
```

А вот как эти запросы объединить? Никак не получается.

Comment: Зависит от диалекта SQL. Если есть FULL OUTER JOIN то объединить им оба запроса. Если нет, то придется его эмулировать через union https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A194569+full+join

Comment: @Mike может быть тогда не стоит заморачиваться и просто делать два запроса?

Comment: не ну знаю, по мне так потом муторно на клиенте собирать по датам.С точки зрения скорости выполнения разницы особо не будет, все равно две разных группировки, как ни крути. максимум что можно оптимизировать company подклеить на последней стадии, но там выигрыш исчезающе мал

Comment: а чем union не устраивает? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)

Comment: @mazzy union без некоторых дополнений не применим так как ТС хочет что бы в одной строке была дата и две колонки с количествами от разных группировок

Comment: @Mike не понимаю проблемы с union. пусть две. в первом select будет ...count(*), 0... а во втором ...0, count(*)...

Comment: @mazzy Ну да, совершенно верно и общая группировка до даты снаружи. О чем я и написал в самом первом комментарии под вопросом

Comment: да, я видел. а зачем общая то? собственно поэтому и влез с вопросом. с union достаточно взять исходные два запроса и всего лишь добавить колонки. https://regex101.com/r/vMi59W/1 разве не? получившийся запрос хорошо распаралеливается, прост для понимания и вообще

Comment: @mazzy попробовал ваш пример с UNION, но результат не тот.... в колонке 0 всё время 0

Comment: да. и много разных строк с одинаковыми `company_id`, `company_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
select company_id,
       date(receipt_date) as "dt",
       count(*)           as "qty"
  into #receipt_total
  from act
where is_delete = 0
group by company_id,
        "dt"
;
-- indexes

select company_id,
       date(receipt_date) as "dt",
       count(*)           as "qty"
  into #issue_total
  from act
where is_delete = 0
group by company_id,
        "dt"
;
-- indexes


select isnull(t1.company_id, t2.company_id) as "company_id",
       isnull(t1.dt, t2.dt)                 as "dt",
       isnull(t1.qty, 0)                    as "qty_receipt",
       isnull(t2.qty, 0)                    as "qty_issue"
  into #result
  from #receipt_total    as t1
  full join #issue_total as t2 on t2.company_id = t1.company_id
                              and t2.dt = t1.dt
;

select t1.company_id,
       t2.company_name,
       t1.dt,
       t1.qty_receipt,
       t1.qty_issue
  from #result as t1
  join company as t2 on t2.id = t1.company_id
;
```

Вариант 2

```
select company_id,
       'receipt'          as "rtype",
       date(receipt_date) as "dt",
       count(*)           as "qty"
  into #receipt_total
  from act
where is_delete = 0
group by company_id,
        "dt"
;
-- indexes

select company_id,
       'issue'            as "rtype",
       date(receipt_date) as "dt",
       count(*)           as "qty"
  into #issue_total
  from act
where is_delete = 0
group by company_id,
        "dt"
;
-- indexes

select *
  into #total_data
  from #receipt_total
union all
select *
  from #issue_total
;

select company_id,
       dt,
       sum(case when rtype = 'receipt'
                 then qty
             end)                        as "qty_receipt",
       sum(case when rtype = 'issue'
                 then qty
             end)                        as "qty_issue"
  into #result
  from #total_data
;

select t1.company_id,
       t2.company_name,
       t1.dt,
       t1.qty_receipt,
       t1.qty_issue
  from #result as t1
  join company as t2 on t2.id = t1.company_id
;
```